# scala function declaration - Inferencer?

Tags: scala, function, function-declaration

I am a scala noob, learning through functional programming in scala book. i was doing some exercises, and this thing really startled me:

```
def plusone[Int](l: List[Int]): List[Int] = foldRight(l, Nil:List[Int])((x,xs)=>Cons(x+1,xs))
```

This is a function that would create a new list with ones added to each elements, but when I wrote this, I got this error:

type mismatch;  found   : Int(1)  required: String  List.scala  /exercises/src/main/scala/fpinscala/datastructures  line 94 Scala Problem

Funny thing is, when I removed that [Int]from my function declaration(so just def plusone, and all others stayed same) I didn't have any error. I am at a loss how to understand this, I would appreciate any help you guys can give me.

FYI, some functions I am using there:
    sealed trait List[+A]

```
case object Nil extends List[Nothing]

case class Cons[+A](head: A, tail: List[A]) extends List[A]

def foldRight[A,B](as: List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B =
as match {
  case Nil => z
  case Cons(x, xs) => f(x, foldRight(xs, z)(f))
}
```

All others should be generic, I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's review the syntax using your examples:

```
def foldRight[A,B](as: List[A], z: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B = ...

def plusone[Int](l: List[Int]): List[Int] = ...

def plusone(l: List[Int]): List[Int] = ...
```

Do you see the difference? Think about it a little bit.

So, what happened is that `def xxx[X]` means make `X` a type variable. In the case where it wasn't working the type of your list wasn't `List[scala.Int]`, it was a list for some type unknown at the declaration of plusone, `Int`, that shadowed `scala.Int`. And that's why it was complaining about the `x+1`.

The reason for this specific error lies the [`Predef.any2stringadd`](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L275) implicit conversion that "augments" all types with a method `def +(String)`.

Comment: Thanks. So unless I want to use a custom type in my function I don't want to add [x] next to function name, right? Makes sense.

Comment: I don't think "custom" really applies here. It's more like that the type doesn't matter.